# Where can I find custom cocoa/xcode class files?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Kind of a noob question, but is there a good way to search for custom controls/objects/frameworks? I was able to stumble upon the Three20 framework and some other things like custom progress bar views and other custom views...but I just kinda 'happened' upon them. Is there any standard place where people post their stuff besides doing a github-wide search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UI elements, check out [Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/). I unfortunately don't know of any other centralized repositories for categories etc. All the useful stuff I've stumbled across came from github, stackoverflow, and/or repeated google searches.

I would recommend staying away from Three20, though. Having used it on some large projects in the past, the framework tended get in the way more than it helped IMHO. Their drawing libraries have some nice conveniences, but it's a lot of bloat to add to your project if you just want a single UI element that the framework provides.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!  Right now I just use Three20 for the photo viewer with the grid view, but a better alternative would be great if you have one?

Comment: Check out http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egophotoviewer. I haven't tried it yet, but enormego made it as an alternative to Three20's photo viewer, so it might be at least a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

One good site that has aggregated a lot of these is http://cocoacontrols.com/